# Attribute directive @Input alias in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning attribute directives in Angular 2. When using `@Input` alias in attribute directives, It will not work, why?

### component

```
<p appHighlight = "color">Hightlight Me</p>
```

### directive

```
export class HighlightDirective {

  @Input('appHighlight') highlightcolor: string;

  constructor(
    // ElementRef is a service that grants direct access to the DOM element through its nativeElement property.
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
    // el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }


  // @HostListener decorator lets you subscribe to events of the DOM element that hosts an attribute directive
  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightcolor || 'red');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseleave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  };

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

}
```

Comment: Renamed input property? What did you mean by that?

Comment: @RemyaJ input alias in Angular 2

Comment: this.highlight(null) ?? How can you set a background as null ? It should be ' transparent' right?

Comment: @RemyaJ This is not the point. I  am reading the document here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Yes. You should have put property binding brackets.

Comment: @RemyaJ That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation should be like this:

```
<p myHighlight [appHighlight]="color">Hightlight Me</p>
```

with the brackets

Assuming the selector is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input('appHighlight') highlightcolor: string;
  ...
```

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/vqZ4gjHc1KNFro62HlVJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

From angular docs -

```
<p HighlightDirective [appHighlight]="inputtedColor">text to highlight</p>
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, OP did not share the directives selector in the question and class name will give an error that it's not bindable to `p` since it's not a known property if selector is something else.

Comment: How can you give input without specifying where to pass the input to. Ok. Now you edited. Now its right

Comment: Yes I made it in the plunker but forgot to add it in my answer :-)